# How to pass an object to an angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I got a directive that looks like this:

```
  .directive('navigation', ['$rootScope', '$i18next', function ($rootScope, $i18next) {
        return {
            bindToController: true,
            templateUrl: 'navigation.tmpl.html',
            link: function (scope , element , attrs) {   ....
```

Implementation

```
<navigation></navigation>
```

How do I add an object to the directive?

Since I will be using this in different places I would like to send an object into the directive so the directive will behave differently depending on the object.

Comment: You need to add property in your scope of directive and pass it from outside. For example your property is `something`. Then your usage should look like `<navigation something=someObject></navigation>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [`bindToController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-bindtocontroller-) you should have a controller (together with `controllerAs`, also `scope` can still be used to define which kind of scope is created) for your `directive`, since this property is used to bind scope properties directly to the directive's controller.

If you don't need a controller, then you can simply use scope bindings to pass the object to your [`directive`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

See both examples below:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function MyCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.test = {val: 10};
  
  $timeout(function(){ 
    $scope.test.val = 111;
  }, 1000);
}])
.directive('navigation1', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
  var navigationDirective1 = {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      bindToController: {
        obj: '='
      },
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      controller: function(){ var ctrl = this; ctrl.$onInit = function onInit(){ console.log(ctrl.obj); }; },
      templateUrl: 'navigation.tmpl.html',
      link: function (scope , element , attrs) {
        console.log(scope.obj); //returns undefined
      }
  }
  return navigationDirective1;
}])
.directive('navigation2', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
  var navigationDirective2 = {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
          obj: '<'
      },
      templateUrl: 'navigation.tmpl.html',
      link: function (scope , element , attrs) {
        console.log(scope.obj);
      }
  }
  return navigationDirective2;
}]);
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">    
    <navigation1 obj="test"></navigation1> 
    --  
    <navigation2 obj="test"></navigation2>
  </div>
  
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="navigation.tmpl.html">
    <div ng-if="vm.obj">
        Hello from directive's controller {{vm.obj}}
    </div>
    <div ng-if="obj">
        Hello from directive's link {{obj}}
    </div>
  </script>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Accepting this as an answer because the resolution is the same as @himanshu and it was posted earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it via scope:

```
.directive('navigation', ['$rootScope', '$i18next', function ($rootScope, $i18next) {
  return {
    scope: {
      objParam: '='
    },
    bindToController: true,
    templateUrl: 'navigation.tmpl.html',
    link: function (scope , element , attrs) {   ....
```

Then your directive becomes:

```
<navigation obj-param="some.object"></navigation>
```

An alternative version:

```
.directive('navigation', ['$rootScope', '$i18next', function ($rootScope, $i18next) {
  return {
    bindToController: {
      objParam: '='
    },
    scope: true,
    templateUrl: 'navigation.tmpl.html',
    link: function (scope , element , attrs) {   ....
```

Comment: I did that but now I'm getting `Error: [$compile:noctrl] Cannot bind to controller without directive 'navigation's controller.`

Comment: I've updated the answer to include bindToController, does that help?

Comment: You need a controller incidentally, that's why you're getting the error I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass object from controller to directive without using **bindToController: true** inside the directive.

Demo controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.Obj={"fName":"John","lName":"Snow"};
});
```

Demo directive

```
app.directive('dirDemo', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            param: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          alert(scope.param.fName);
          alert(scope.param.lName);
            }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
     <div dir-demo
            param="Obj"
    </div>
  </body>
```

Plunker demo https://plnkr.co/edit/A5E542OJRwuGQj5wQ4sl?p=preview

If you still want to use **bindToController** then you need to mention **controller** name inside directive as below

Demo directive

```
app.directive('dirDemo', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            param: '='
        },
        bindToController: true,
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          alert(scope.ctrl.param.fName);
          alert(scope.Obj.lName);
            }
    }
});
```

Plunker demo https://plnkr.co/edit/3j7Sh317K0EKOed8nkpb?p=preview

Comment: I'm getting `Cannot read property 'fName' of undefined` on the later demo.

Comment: Oh my bad. I have forgotten to save the latest. Now its done. You can check.